# Writing into file results in gibberish Java

Tags: java, file, writer

I'm trying to write some numbers into a *.txt file, using write.write() function. When I open the created file with notepad I see gibberish, but when I open with notepad++, the file is ok. Can anyone explain why is this happening?

```
try {
        for(int i = 0; i < predictionsList.size(); i ++){
            writer.write(Integer.toString(predictionsList.get(i)));
            writer.write("\n");
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Please show the code you use to write the file.

Comment: Probably a character encoding issue

Comment: Please show us the code. But I can imagine what you are doing. The file opened in Notepad++ displays ok and not in notepad means only one thing. The line ending character. Notepad requires it to be \r\n, but Notepad++ can understand if it is \r or \n or both. Check what your code is doing and please post as much as details.

Comment: You are probably writing a Unicode file without the proper byte order mark.  Google it.  Notepad++ is probably doing a sanity check and handles it as Unicode even though the byte order mark is missing, whereas Notepad will just read it as ANSI.

Answer (score 0):

The information you provide in the question is not enough, even though we can infer that your issue is related    with the encoding of the text file you are writing

Verify the BOM format, that is by default selected in notepad++